# Apply a udf filtering function in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, multiprocessing, bigdata, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to filter and sum the values in a specific range of a pyspark dataframe. It works when I use this code:

```
load_1=[]
for i in range(df.count()):
    start_t = df.select('start_time').where(df.id == i).collect()[0][0]
    try:
        load_1.append(df.where((df.start_time <= start_t) & (start_t <= df.end_time_1)).agg({"pkt_size":"sum"}).collect()[0][0])
    except:
        load_1.append(0)
```

But it is pretty slow. I was tryin to speed it up with a udf and did this:

```
def get_load(a, df=df):
    try:
        return df.where((df.start_time <= a) & (a <= df.end_time_1)).agg({"pkt_size":"sum"}).collect()[0][0]
    except:
        return 0

loader = f.udf(get_load)
df.withColumn('load_1', loader(df.start_time).show())
```

When using this method I'm getting this error:

```
Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Any idea on how I can solve this or how I can speed it up? I'm trying to do something like the function apply that we do in pandas. The data is pretty large (nearly 40G) and the more resource I can use the better.
Thanks in advance! Here is a sample of the data:

```
+---+-------------+-----------------+--------+
| id|   start_time|       end_time_1|pkt_size|
+---+-------------+-----------------+--------+
|  1|1000000000000| 1.00000000192E12|    66.0|
|  2|1000000000000| 1.00000000192E12|    66.0|
|  3|1000000006478|1.000000008398E12|    66.0|
|  4|1000000006478|1.000000008398E12|    66.0|
|  5|1000000012956|1.000000014556E12|    58.0|
|  6|1000000012956|1.000000014556E12|    58.0|
|  7|1000000012957|1.000000016156E12|  1518.0|
|  8|1000000012957|1.000000016156E12|  1518.0|
|  9|1000000012957|1.000000017756E12|  1518.0|
| 10|1000000012957|1.000000017756E12|  1518.0|
| 11|1000000012957|1.000000019356E12|  1518.0|
| 12|1000000012957|1.000000019356E12|  1518.0|
| 13|1000000012957|1.000000020956E12|  1518.0|
| 14|1000000012957|1.000000020956E12|  1518.0|
| 15|1000000012957|1.000000022556E12|  1518.0|
| 16|1000000012957|1.000000022556E12|  1518.0|
| 17|1000000012957|1.000000024156E12|  1518.0|
| 18|1000000012957|1.000000024156E12|  1518.0|
| 19|1000000012957|1.000000025756E12|  1518.0|
| 20|1000000012957|1.000000025756E12|  1518.0|
+---+-------------+-----------------+--------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

The goal is to sum up the pkt_size of all the rows that have a start_time smaller than the start_time of each id and an end_time larger that the start_time of the id. So the filter is based on the start_time of each row.

Comment: Could you provide some example data to illustrate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I just added a few lines. The issue is that the filter values change based on the start_time of each row of data and should be calculated for all id's based on their start_time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to achieve the result without a loop or udf:

Using the test data

```
+---+----------+----------+--------+                                            
| id|start_time|end_time_1|pkt_size|
+---+----------+----------+--------+
|  1|         2|         5|       4|
|  2|         1|         6|       5|
|  3|         1|         7|       6|
|  4|         5|         6|       7|
|  5|         4|         7|       8|
|  6|         3|         8|       9|
|  7|         6|         7|      10|
+---+----------+----------+--------+
```

the code

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [(1, 2, 5, 4), 
        (2, 1, 6, 5),
        (3, 1, 7, 6),
        (4, 5, 6, 7),
        (5, 4, 7, 8),
        (6, 3, 8, 9),
        (7, 6, 7, 10)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=['id', 'start_time', 'end_time_1', 'pkt_size'])

df.select('id', 'start_time', 'end_time_1') \
    .join(df.selectExpr('start_time as st_1', 'end_time_1 as et_1', 'pkt_size'), \
        F.expr('st_1 < start_time and et_1 > end_time_1')) \
    .groupBy('id') \
    .agg(F.sum('pkt_size')) \
    .show()
```

prints

```
+---+-------------+
| id|sum(pkt_size)|
+---+-------------+
|  7|            9|
|  5|            9|
|  1|           11|
|  4|           23|
+---+-------------+
```

In this example, for id 1 the rows 2 and 3 are added and for id 4 the rows 3, 5 and 6.

The logic is the same as in the question, but the calculation is performed for all ids in parallel instead of one after the other. This approach requires a self join so the Spark cluster should be large enough.